# Keeping a SQL Server Database Project and the Actual Database (in SSMS) in sync during development

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, database-project

I am trying to figure out what the normal workflow should be between a SQL Server Database Project and the actual database in SQL Server (SSMS) once they are in sync. The main reason I am using one of these projects is to keep everything in Source Control.

**Here are the steps I took to set things up:**

1. Create the actual database and entire schema in SQL Server Management Studio.
2. Create a new SQL Server Database Project in VS2015.
3. Right click the project and import the actual database.

Now that the project is in sync with the actual database, how should I go about making changes going forward? Do I make them in the database project and then republish it or do I make them in the schema? Basically what I am saying is that I am trying to avoid making schema changes during development in both places.

Answer (score 3):

Generally the best practice will be to make changes to the project, check that into source control, and publish the changes to your database as needed.  Your project then becomes your source. You can branch it, merge it, and do whatever else is needed to do your development.  You won't be republishing your database, though. You'll update your existing one when you publish your project. It will do a diff between your project and the db, then make the appropriate updates/alters to bring your database in line w/ the project.

I blogged about my experiences with SSDT here: http://schottsql.blogspot.com/search/label/SSDT, but there are some other great resources available if you look. There are definitely different ways to do things and what I chose may not fit your environment exactly.

Comment: Interestingly in a survey we ran on database project users at Redgate we learned that the majority of users make changes to their dev database first, rather than making them offline. I suspect that this is because there's overhead in waiting for the F5 build.

Comment: Well, I'll make changes to the DB first, but one of the reasons that SQL Source Control gave me fits was that I felt I'd need to bring my DB in line w/ the current branch first then make my changes. I'll make the changes locally (intellisense helps), but copy the script into SSDT pretty shortly afterwards. For tables, I'll typically use ER Studio first, get agreement on the model, then add to source control. However, pushes to shared environments all come from that SSDT project.  The rest is just scratch-work.

Comment: Have you tried ReadyRoll yet? This supports connected development in Visual Studio thereby avoiding the overhead of your "copy the script" step.

Comment: I have not tried that yet. I'm not as worried about the connected development part, though. A lot of times when I'm playing with the local instance, I'm working out some ideas before it's finalized. Especially with stored procs/views, I go through many iterations before I tend to check in just because I'm working out the different behaviors, performance, etc.  I'll take a look at the project to see what it does, though. :)

Comment: Exactly. ReadyRoll recognizes this by treating "programmable objects" differently. I think you'll like it. http://doc.ready-roll.com/display/RRSQLDOC/Programmable+Objects